# Connect to MySQL on my laptop from Raspberry pi

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I have a MySQLdb running on my Ubuntu Laptop. I have created a database.
I need to access this database on  my laptop from my Raspberry pi.

I have installed PyMySQL on my raspberry pi. I have also configured the mysqld.conf file in my laptop and commented out the bind address line.

But eherytime i use the following command on my RPi

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='192.168.10.7', port='3306', user='root', passwd='password', db='temps')
```

192.168.10.7 is my laptop ip address. This IP address can be pinged from my RPi.

but i get error

```
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1130, "Host '192.168.10.7' is not allowed to connect to this MSQL server")
```

Do I need to make anymore changes in the configuration? If yes, can you please guide me?

Comment: Have you commented out the bind-address parameter in the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file? Do this on the ubuntu laptop

Answer (score 0):

By default MySQL Server on Ubuntu run on the local interface, This means remote access to the MySQL Server is not Allowed. To enable remote connections to the MySQL Server you need to change value of the bind-address in the MySQL Configuration File.
Open the /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf file (/etc/mysql/my.cnf in Ubuntu 14.04 and earlier versions).
Under the [mysqld] Locate the Line,

```
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

**And change it to,**

```
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

Then, Restart the Ubuntu MysQL Server.
systemctl restart mysql.service

Now Ubuntu Server will allow remote access to the MySQL Server, But still you need to configure MySQL users to allow access from any host.
For example, when you create a MySQL user, you should allow access from any host.

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```